# Mobile app picture

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, windows-mobile, blackberry-playbook

Is there an easy way to get images of a smart phone/tablet with an application we need in it?

I can pull my app in my smart phone and take a photo of it. But it may not look as sleek as it looks in these [app sites](http://appsites.com/). Is there any software which helps on this?

Any JQuery kind of plugin to simulate the same? Like an image slider with Android phone image as frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/device-frames.html

This is the best way ... devleoped by Roman Nurik of Google

Comment: Any similar thing iOS, Windows phone and BB playbook?

Comment: Not that I know of... I found a PSD a while back for iPhone 4 ... could then replace screen in Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks Tony.. I may end-up doing that for other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip- for the above android link, you can re-size your screenshot to suit the required pixel in that link. There are bunch of online image resize utils out there!